# Method that adds elements to set always throwing custom exception

Tags: java

Ok, so I've got a method which adds elements to a list but it is always throwing my custom exception, no matter what, even when there are no elements in the `Set` I made.

```
private Set<Plan> planSet = new HashSet<Plan>();
public Plan createPlan(String name) throws DuplicatePlan{
    Plan plan = new Plan(name);


    if(!planSet.contains(plan)){
        planSet.add(plan);
    } else {
        throw(new DuplicatePlan("Error, duplicate plan"));
    }

    return plan;
}
```

I'm thinking that my `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are causing this. Currently I'm using the default overridden Eclipse `hashCode()` and `equals()`, this is what I've got there:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj){
        return true;
    } if (obj == null){
        return false;
    } if (getClass() != obj.getClass()){
        return false;
            }
    Plan other = (Plan) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null){
            return false;
                    }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)){
        return false;
            }
    return true;
}
```

This is what `Plan` does:

```
private String name;
private Set<Tables> tablesSet;


public Plan(String name){
    this.name = name ;
}
```

Here's what's supposed to happen if a user sets the same name in the TextField:

```
newPlan.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent action){
            if(!newPlan.getText().isEmpty()){
                try {
                    String name = planName.getText();
                    plan.createPLan(name);
                    esquema =             esquemas.createPlan(planName.getText());
                    optionsPlans.getItems().add(plan.getName());
                } catch (DuplicatePlan e) {
                    dialog.errorDialog(planError, duplicate);
                }
            } else {
                dialog.errorDialog(empty, emptySpace);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does the `Plan(String)` constructor do?  And what does the full stacktrace look like?

Comment: Please don't ever mix _if_ with braces and without braces, or go ahead and always use braces. Makes it hard for everyone to read your code

Comment: @JuanMendes In fairness, it's generated code, and it's indented. But yeah, always use braces :)

Comment: Do you have subclasses of Plan?

Comment: @ChrisMantle Maybe, but it doesn't mean it's easy to read, fix it it before posting, be nice to others (and to yourself so that others will want to look at your question)

Comment: What you have posted so far seems OK. The problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do that, Eclipse generate equals() and hashCode() that way.

Comment: Your code works for me when I tested it in an [sscce](http://sscce.org). You should create your own and post it here so we can find the error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Best thing OP can do, show the code we can run to reproduce it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if it makes you feel better, I typed in and almost posted the same answer you deleted :)

Comment: All right I'm going to place the try/catch that I used for this statement in my UI class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use Answer because it was too long for comment.
This here looks suspicious to me:

```
String name = planName.getText();
plan.createPLan(name);
esquema = esquemas.createPlan(planName.getText());
```

I.e. what's up with `createPLan` and `createPlan`? Copy & paste error? Or are you calling the same method twice (which would explain the behavior)?

Comment: You were right, thank you, I was instantiating the object two times, thus adding it twice to my Set